# How to avoid 503s when using MS Graph APIs Delta syncing feature?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When I use the MS Graph api to fetch event deltas for a calendar view or message deltas for a mailbox using the supplied delta token or skip token, I periodically get 503 unknown errors.  Multiplied by hundreds of calendars or mailboxes, I get the 503 errors very frequently.

Sometimes, re-fetching without the delta token or skip token, I am able to retrieve the entire dataset rather than just the changes, but that is very slow, and then when I try to incrementally sync using the new delta token, I get a 503 again.

Sometimes, restricting `odata.maxpagesize=2` helps alleviate some 503s temporarily, but sometimes it grinds to a failure and still hits the 503.

How can I avoid getting 503 errors?

I can supply request IDs and stuff if someone at Microsoft wants to dig into this.